# Build only war file in target folder

Tags: java, maven, build

Im building a web application using maven but in the target folder appears anothers folders (classes, test-classes, generated-sources, etc) and my war file.
I want keep only the war file in the target folder after the build. How can i get this?

Comment: Yes but i don't see how can i keep the .war file after made a clean after the build.
I thing that can copy the war file to another folder but i haven't idea how to do it

Comment: Why would you like to keep the war file in the target directory?